# Convert NSString to date error

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm having a strange issue converting a string to a date:

```
NSString *goodDateString = @"2012-06-28 16:08:56.871000";
NSString *badDateString = @"2012-06-28 16:11:17.999771";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSDate *goodDate = [formatter dateFromString:goodDateString];
NSDate *badDate = [formatter dateFromString:badDateString];

NSAssert(goodDate, @"date is nil"); //passes this test
NSAssert(badDate, @"date is nil"); //fails this test
```

For some reason, the badDateString returns nil when I try to convert it to a date. I have no idea why. Is there something wrong with the date string?

**Edit:** The strings are coming from a Python server. I'm using `dateString = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')` on this date: `2012-06-28 16:11:17` which returns `2012-06-28 16:11:17.999771` which is unable to be parsed by the date formatter above. Any python people know how I can limit the last part of the date to 3 decimal places rather than 6?

Comment: What is 871000? Milisecond?? or something else?

Comment: I don't see that '%f' is a valid format specifier to be passed to Python's strftime. But if it works, maybe try changing it to '%.3f'.

Comment: No that didn't work. What worked was: `date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] `

Comment: Did my answer help? Once you truncated the date did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it may be a bug. It has to do with the fact that [`SSS`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) rounds the fractional seconds 999771 up to the next whole second and for some reason that causes the format to fail. If you changed the fractional seconds to `999499` it would work, but simply changing it to `9995` will cause it to fail. I would consider filing a [bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/) and adding it to [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/). In the mean-time just write code to truncate the fractional seconds past 3 digits.